# How can I use a pound sign (£) in a contains selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide all select options which contain £0.00 but the £ sign isn't passing through properly. Is there a way to use this within a selector?

I've tried several ways of passing the pound sign but none seem to work (setting as variable, using unicode etc)

This is what I have in the source code:

```
$('option:contains(£0.00)').hide();
```

This is what displays when I go into 'view source':

```
$('select option:contains(Â£0.00)').remove();
```

Comment: That is working just fine for me, try and look here https://jsfiddle.net/1y7o84x0/

Comment: You can use the ASCII code for HTML: &pound;

Comment: Yep, working fine for me too: https://jsfiddle.net/7xtr9czo/

Comment: This works fine for me too.

Comment: It works when I do it in the console but when it's done inside a document ready function it doesn't work. I've made it load as the last thing on the page too and also made sure the structure of the dropdown is the same as the fiddle. It's generated in an ASP tag but the output is pretty much the same!!

Comment: can someone tell me why they down voted this? It's a genuine question and I can't find any answers online...

Comment: This feels like a page encoding issue. Does your page have a `<meta charset=...` tag? Does the server send a `Content-Type` header? If so what value are either of these?

Comment: @phuzi It's <meta charset="utf-8" /> at present

Comment: What editor are you using to edit your code? Does it think the source is UTF8?

Comment: It's Notepad++ and appears to be encoding UTF-8

Comment: I can replicate this by creating a empty file with a single `£` in it saving it as UTF8. If I reopen the file (with VS Code) with ISO 8859-1 encoding it shows up as `Â£`. There's definitely something weird with the encoding/the way it is being presented to the browser.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head there. When I copied everything out of notepad++ and saved it in actual windows notepad, it seems to have encoded properly and now works! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with encoding. Notepad++ was set to UTF-8 but when I took the code from Notepad++, pasted it into an actual windows Notepad .txt file, then saved it from there - it encoded properly and the strange character preceding the £ sign disappeared.

Thanks @phuzi for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quote in contains and remove, it will work only if string matches exactly:

```
$('select option:contains("£0.00")').remove();
```

Comment: This works in the console but when I put it in the code it doesn't detect :<

Answer (score -1):

You can loop your option and check if text is = £0.00

```
$('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == '£0.00'){
        $(this).hide();
    }
})
```

this should works.

check in HTML if your Pound sign is printed by a htmlentities or other, it could be fail your selector https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/pound-sign/

if '£0.00' is not the only text contained into your option node youcan use indexOf to check if a string contains another

so the upper code turns into this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>£0.00</option>
<option>Some text £0.00</option>
<option>£23.00</option>
<option>£1.00 some other text</option>
<option>£0.00 some other text</option>
</select>
<script>
 jQuery('option').each(function(){
            // if ($(this).text().includes('£0.00')){.....
            // or
            console.log($(this).text())
            console.log($(this).text().indexOf('£0.00'))
            if($(this).text().indexOf('£0.00') > -1){
                //$(this).hide()
                $(this).css({background: 'red'});
            }
        })
</script>
```

Comment: That might work but I need to detect if it contains £0.00 because there's text preceding this (Adult, OAP, Child etc)

Comment: @HunterForest answer updated to check if option text contains

Comment: Unfortunately we've tried that and it still doesn't detect the £. It seems to work fine when we take the £ sign out, but that gives us the problem of detecting 10.00, 20.00 when really we want to just detect £0.00

Comment: @HunterForest i add a snippet

Comment: It still won't pass through the £ sign properly, and looking in the source code of the rendered page it looks to pull through as Â£0.00 instead of £0.00